# PowerShell Get-Childitem top level folder only

Tags: powershell, directory, size

I am trying to obtain the information (`Size`, `LastWriteTime`) about a set of folders. I only need to know for the top level folders i.e. c:\Logs, C:\Storage, D:\backup, I don't want to know the information on what those folder have inside.

I have written a script which almost meets my requirement but the problem is, the script goes through the contents of those folders rather than just looking at the parent folder only (d:\backup etc...)

```
$path = Import-Csv C:\Users\pshell\Desktop\paths.csv

Foreach ($paths in $path) {
  get-childitem $paths.path | where {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
    select-object FullName, Name, Creationtime, @{Name="MB";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB}}, 
         LastAccessTime, @{Name="Owner";Expression={(Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner}}

}
```

It is giving me the information I need but in a greater depth which I do not wish to have at this stage.

What I do not understand is why `Get-Childitem` is not looking at the top level folders only? I mean I have not used the `-Recurse` switch so it should only scan the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` gets the child items (e.g the contents) of the paths you are given. Thats why it looks like its recursing, because it's showing you all the folders that are inside those paths, but not the contents of those folders (that would require `-Recurse`).

If you just want to retrieve information about the paths, you should probably use `Get-Item`, but beware you can't retrieve the size of a Windows path without iterating through its contents.

This would be one way to get the size of each path (I am assuming that what you want is the total size of the path including subfolders, if not remove `-recurse` to just get the size of the files in that particular folder):

```
$path = @(@{path = 'C:\temp'},@{path = 'c:\users'})

Foreach ($paths in $path)
{
    $Size = (Get-ChildItem $paths.path -File -Recurse | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum
    Get-Item -Path $paths.path | select-object FullName, Name, Creationtime, @{Name="MB";Expression={$Size / 1MB}}, LastAccessTime, @{Name="Owner";Expression={(Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner}}
}
```

Comment: how would that work in my case? I mean, Can powershell iterate through its contents but dont display it, at the end, it should be give me folder size and last write time etc...? I dont think that is possible with powershell? thanks for reply.

Comment: ahhh, sorry for my eagerness.